# Homological proof of $$-primary decomposition of torsion abelian groups

Tags: homology-cohomology, derived-functors, primary-decomposition

It is known that torsion abelian groups decompose as direct sums of their $$-primary components. Is there any homological proof of this fact using derived functors?

It can be proved by hand but I wondered if there is a nicer proof using derived functors? (I suspected Tor functor).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Isn’t Tor a left-derived functor though?

Comment: Right thank you, I removed the mistaken part.